# Google Sheet: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use a AutoSort Script to sort data using Column CY on addition of any new row

```
function autoSort(e) {
  const row = e.range.getRow()
  const column = e.range.getColumn()
  const ss = e.source
  const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName()

  if(!(currentSheetName === "Final Data" && column ===103 && row >=2)) return
 
  const range = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,103)

  range.sort({column: 103, ascending: false})

}
function onEdit(e) {
  autoSort(e)
}
```

I get an error on running the script as follows
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

What exactly is going wrong? Please guide!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `ss = e.source`. Try

```
function autoSort(e) {
  const row = e.range.getRow()
  const column = e.range.getColumn()
  //const ss = e.source
  const currentSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName()

  if(!(currentSheetName === "Final Data" && column ===1 && row >=2)) return
 
  var range = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,103)

  range.sort({column: 103, ascending: false})

}
function onEdit(e) {
  autoSort(e)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.
I seek another help. How can I use this code on multiple workbooks(not the same sheet). One way is to copy & paste the code in each workbook. Is there any smarter way to run it without individual copy paste across workbooks.

Comment: Yes, I think you can do it using library, but I'm not familiar with this, it would need to ask a question or do some research. https://www.google.com/search?q=personal+library+google+app+script